# Is it possible to hover a TextView above an ImageButton?

Tags: android, textview, imagebutton

I have an image that has the title of the field I want and a little box where I want to display a number. Is it possible to hover a textview on top of an image view button? So it looks like the following:
[image]

Comment: +1 Cephron.  You've asked 6 questions all of which have answers.  If the answer was what you used throw out the check mark.  If the answer was helpful give it an up vote.  People will gladly help you if you throw some props their way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developer site has an example of exactly what you're trying to do.  They use a framelayout.  http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html